# Deploy VS solution (List) to all users' "My Site"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, my-site, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment

I wrote a custom document library that we use to manage our Proof of Activities at work. I used VS2012 for development and our portal is based on SP2013.

Is there any way besides PowerShell to deploy the solution to all user's **"My Site"** pages without exporting/importing the .wsp file?

Comment: You could use feature stapling.

Comment: What's wrong with powershell?

Comment: @Aveenav Correct me if I'm wrong. But I dont think that works on already provisioned mysites.

Comment: I can use PS, but only as a last resort. Why, I do not know, it has been one of the requirements.

Comment: what you mean exporting and Importing the wsp?

Comment: Yes, feature stapling will only work new sites. I think either powershell or new App provisioning method through App catalog should work. Read more about App stapling here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/03/04/sharepoint-2013-app-deployment-through-quot-app-stapling-quot.aspx

Comment: No experience with this, would be nice to give it a try! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see two possible ways for doing this.

First: Try to convince your client to launch a very simple powershell script for activating the solution throughout the mysite web application. You can give the script to their administrators for them to analyze and run if they're set on it.

Second: If you're REALLY set on not using powershell. Edit the profile page and add a script to it. This script will run each time and try to activate the feature in the user's stead. It's not really a very nice solution imo.

The REST URL you can use for activating the feature is this one:

```
http://sitecollection/site/_api/web/features/add(featureId,force,featdefScope)
```

Additional information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245237(v=office.15).aspx